# Retornar la clase modelo o VistaModelo?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tengo un problema de diseño, actualmente tengo una vista que solo utilizo información de mi modelo usuario classe. Lo que en la vista no necesito toda la información del modelo lo que debería crear una clase extra viewmodel con la información necesaria o puedo retronar la clase usuario directamente a la vista?

```
return View(user);
```

o

```
return View(new UserViewModel(user));
```

Ya que en el caso que tenga que hacer un vewModel único para esa vista, cuando este en otras vistas que necesiten otro tipo de información del usuario, tendré que crear otro viewmodel con las propiedades que sean necesarias para la vista?

Gracias por la ayuda!

Answer (score 2):

Puedes utilizar como modelo la clase User aunque tenga más información de la que precisa la vista. Es una decisión que deberás tomar durante el desarrollo: cuándo crear una nueva clase como modelo de vista y cuando reutilizar una existente.

Para tomar esta decisión las cuestiones que tenderás que tener en cuenta son:

- La claridad del código
- Si la vista necesita información adicional a la contenida en la clase (en tal caso sería recomendable crear un modelo de vista)
- Posibles problemas de seguridad

Cuando hablo de problemas de seguridad me refiero a que tendrás que tener en cuenta que en la información recibida desde el navegador puede incluir propiedades que no utilices en la vista.

Por ejemplo si la clase User tiene las propiedades Code, Name, Surname, Age, Email. Puedes crear una vista en la que únicamente muestres controles para editar, por ejemplo, el nombre y el apellido (Name y Surname). Sin embargo, si un usuario malintencionado añade a la información del post al hacer submit del formulario un valor con clave Email, MVC bindeará automáticamente este valor a la propiedad del objeto User recibido en el controlador. Deberías entonces tener en cuenta en tu código que el valor de esta propiedad podría haber sido modificado por el usuario aunque no hayas dado la posibilidad de editarlo en el formulario.

Si utilizas una clase de modelo de vista con únicamente las propiedades Name y Surname este caso no podría darse.

Answer (score 2):

**>>debería crear una clase extra viewmodel con la información necesaria o puedo retronar la clase usuario directamente a la vista?**

Depende, no hay una regla que indique que tienes que convertir la entidad a un viewmodel para usarla en la view, aunque si seria recomendable, mas que nada por la definicion de validaciones usando `Data Annotations`.

Cuando agregas atributos en las propiedades de la clase estas modficandola y esto seria recomendable no hacerlo sobre la entidad que luego usas en la capa de negocio o persistencia.

**>>cuando este en otras vistas que necesiten otro tipo de información del usuario, tendré que crear otro viewmodel con las propiedades que sean necesarias para la vista?**

Exacto, es mas puede que tengas un viewmodel con datos minimos para listar en una tabla y luego otro mas detallado con las propiedades para la edicion

Recuerda que puede usar herencia entre estas clases y asi no definir todas las propiedades